# pythonを用いています。以下のプログラムが作れなくて困っています。

Tags: python, python3

問題は「ハイフンで結合された単語の文字列を入力とし、ソートされた単語をハイフンで結合した文字列を返す関数を定義しなさい」です。
実装例として、以下
def hyphen_sorted(connectedstring):

print(hyphen_sorted('red-green-blue'))

実行例として
'blue-green-red'
となるようにしたいです。

Comment: [以下を実行するコードを教えてください](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10227519440)

Comment: スタックオーバーフローではプログラムの作成依頼的な質問は回答が集まりづらい傾向があります。動かなくても構わないのでご自身が試したテストコードや試行錯誤した履歴を載せるととより回答が集まりやすいでしょう。

Comment: あなたの今の質問は、あなたがPythonをどれぐらい知っているのがサッパリ分かりません。そうなると、Pythonの知識が全くないという前提にせざるを得ず、「困っていること」を解決する手段は「Pythonを勉強して下さい。そうすれば、作れるようになります」しかなくなります。そのような回答を望んでいるのですか？

Answer (score 1):

Split
Sorted
Join
あたり組み合わせればなんとかなりそう

Comment: 具体的に教えてもらえませんか？

Comment: プログラムを書いていただけるとありがたいです。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

Splitは文字列を分解する時に使用します。
ここではred-green-blueを-で分解し、バラバラにします。
その後、Sortedでソートし、Joinでつなぎ合わせます。
スタックオーバーフローでは宿題の答えそのもの回答を求めることは、
あまりよく思われません。
ヒントを元に自分でプログラムを書いてみて、それがうまく動作しない場合は、
再度質問すれば、回答してもらえると思います。

Answer (score 0):

あまりシンプルではないですが、書いてみました。
こんな感じでどうでしょうか。

```
def hyphen_sorted(connectedstring):
    string_list = connectedstring.split('-')
    string_list.sort()
    return '-'.join(string_list)

print(hyphen_sorted('red-green-blue'))
```